# EF6 not loading child entities with alphanumeric IDs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Given the following tables:

```
SCHOOL
    schoolid (int PK)
    name
TEACHER
    teacherId (int PK)
    name, homeRoomId (fk varchar10)
    subjectId (fk varchar10)
    schoolid (FK int)
HOMEROOM
    homeRoomId (PK varchar10)
    roomNumber
    active
SUBJECT
    subjectId (PK varchar10)
    name
    active
```

I am using EF6 in an MVC app.  I have lazy loading enabled.  I am trying to return a list of all teachers for a given `SchoolId` and I need to include homeroom and subject data for each teacher.

A school contains many teachers, a teacher works for only one school, a teacher has only one homeroom and teachs only one subject.  The homeroom and subject ids are varchars because they are pre-existing ids and look like: SUBJECT: A03, Math.

My code to load all teachers with homeroom and subject for a single `schoolid`:

```
public List<TeacherModel> GetTeachersBySchool(int schoolId)
{
    List<TeacherModel> teachers = new List<TeacherModel>();

    using (var db = new myDBEntities())
    {
        var list = db.Teacher.Where(a => a.SchoolId == schoolId).ToList();

        foreach ( var s in list)
        {
            TeacherModel teacher = new TeacherModel()
            {
                TeacherId = s.TeacherId,
                Name = s.Name,
                HomeRoomId = s.HomeRoomId,
                HomeRoomNumber = s.HomeRoom.RoomNumber,
                SubjectId = s.SubjectId,
                SubjectName = s.Subject.Name
            };
            teachers.Add(teacher);
        }
        return teachers;
    }
}
```

The homeroom entity is loading but the Subject entity is null even through a sql query in the database returns one row for this teacher. Due to the null Subject entity, the query errors out as object reference not set to blah blah.

I have found that the problem seems to be when the SubjectId contains alpha characters.  A couple examples of a subjectid are: "A03" or "1001023".  The second entity will load, the first will not.  I assume that even though the datatype is string/varchar EF6 is pulling out the numeric values and passing those as the id, so if the ID has alphas, it fails.

Does this jibe? How do I fix it?  As a last resort I can add a surrogate key (INT Identity 1,1) for use with these entities but I'm hoping there is another way.

Comment: I've not had trouble with string keys. What does the C# entity class look like? Does the type match the table?

Comment: I am doing DB first so the edmx is generated from existing database. I did double check in the TT files that the data types match.

Comment: What if you use `db.Teacher.Include(t => t.Subject)`? Also check the generated SQL for this query and run it as SQL to check its result. `Include` is better anyway, because your code loads each `Subject` (and `HomeRoom`) separately. There's more to improve, but first this joining issue must be solved.

Comment: Isn't include for eager loading?  I thought the reason for lazy loading was so you don't have to specify this stuff.  If I use Include, do I have to disable lazy loading, or is it implied?

Comment: I tried adding includes(), no difference.  I have noticed that sometimes the SubjectId is passed as 'A03' and other times with a bunch of trailing spaces like  'A03             '.(this editor is truncating the spaces, sp just imagine 7 spaces after A03).

Comment: Have you tried removing the table from your edmx file and re-adding?

Comment: Yes.I have removed just the teacher table, then all three tables, Iv'e rebuilt, heck I even closed everything and rebooted my box, no help.  I just ran a test with a numeric subject id (21) though it is still a a string, and it returned a subject but now the homeroom entity was null. Is it only able to return one related entity?

Comment: If you query for a `Subject` with `id = 'A03'` in code, do you get it? I wonder if you have hidden chars in your Subject ids which are causing problems.

Comment: Yes, this query returns results:  select * from Teacher where subjectId = 'A03'

Comment: I assume that the foreign keys are hard foreign key constraints in the database? If so, you can't have FK values that don't match any PK value. Trailing spaces are ignored in Sql Server, so that shouldn't be an issue either. Also, EF doesn't do any matching itself, it delegates the whole query to the database and just processes the returned result set. So again, try `Include`, check the generated SQL and run it in SSMS. As I said, `Include` is recommended (and no, you don't have to disable lazy loading).